# Get the id of the clicked-upon div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select the `id` of the current div when I click on it in jQuery.
For example, say I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="item"  id="10">hello world</div>
<div class="item_10">hello people</div>
```

When I click on the first div on `.item` class, I want to copy the `id` of the current div + adding to it the number (10), so it will be `("div id" + 10)` equal to the second dev class = item_10.

I tried to use `currentid = this.id;` but it doesnt work :( !

Comment: For future reference, note that "it doesn't work" is not very helpful to those trying to help you. You included a pretty good description of what you have and what you want, so +1 for that. Better, however, is to include an actual working test case (http://jsfiddle.net) and instead of saying "it doesn't work", say what happened instead. Did you get an error? Did you get the wrong result? Did your computer catch fire?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, note that `id` attributes starting with numbers are syntactically illegal in HTML4. If you're using `id="10"` make sure that you're using the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`).

It's hard to say why what you were doing didn't work without seeing your actual code. Presumably it is because you were registering for the event on a higher element (like the body) and `this.id` was the `id` of that higher element and not the element you clicked on.

In this case, you want to use the `target` property of the event to find what you clicked on. For example:

```
$(document.body).click(function(evt){
  var clicked = evt.target;
  var currentID = clicked.id || "No ID!";
  $(clicked).html(currentID);
})
```

Seen in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Gra2P/

If you were registering on the specific elements instead, then `this.id` *does* work:

```
$('div').click(function(evt){
  var currentID = this.id || "No ID!";
  $(this).html(currentID);
})
```

Seen in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Gra2P/1/

This is sub-ideal, however, because:

1. It makes many event handler registrations instead of 1, and
2. If additional divs are added to the document after this code is run, they will not be processed.

Under jQuery 1.7, you use the `.on` method to create a single event handler on a parent element with selectors for the kinds of elements you want to catch the event on, and have `this` set to them. In code:

```
$(document.body).on('click','div',function(evt){
  var currentID = this.id || "No ID!";
  $(this).html(currentID);
})
```

Seen in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Gra2P/2/

Comment: +1 for explainaing all the various options (including why `this.id` might not work) and not using `$(this).attr('id')`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to do something like:

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var el = $(".item_" + id);
});
```

Now el is your second div.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `this.id`

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var divid = this.id;
    alert($('.item_'+divid).html());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lgff/)

Comment: +1 - Finally someone who uses the simpler and faster `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`.  jQuery should be used only when actually better.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    theId = $(this).attr('id');
    //Do whatever you want with theId.
});
```

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but perhaps it's because you're using jQuery unnecessarily. `$(this).attr('id')` is a slower and more verbose way of writing `this.id`…which the OP already said "didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as:

```
$('.item').click(function() {
var divId = $(this).attr("id");

});
```