# click function for parent and child id

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="main_div" style="border:1px solid black;height:20%;width:40%;">
  <div id="first">first div<div>
  <div id="second">second div</div>
  <input id="third" type="text" value=""/>
</div>
```

what i want is that when i click on child elements of main_div i want to get there id and when i click on main_div that is the parent element i can get its id by using a single click function. And the constraint is that i cannot give some classes to parent and child elements.

Comment: `$('#main_id').click(function(e){alert($(e.target).attr('id'));});`?

Comment: Didn't you ask this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329271/getting-id-of-elements-inside-the-div

Comment: ya but in that i forgot to ask how to get the parent elements id

Comment: OK it's _slightly_ different :-)

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
$('#main_div').on('click', function(e){
   alert(e.target.id);
});
```

for jQuery < 1.7 use

```
$('#main_div').click(function(e){
   alert(e.target.id);
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7TXjF/

Comment: +1 although I'll clarify that this syntax requires jQuery 1.7 minimum

Comment: @andyb yes of course, if you use .click() it works in any version

Answer (score 2):

Since your question has a jquery tag I will respond with a jquery answer.

```
$("#main_div").click(function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).attr("id"));
});
```

Also see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wEPHh/1/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick ...

```
$('#main_div,#first,#second,#third').click(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: yeas, but this attaches three event handlers and makes one unnecessari jQuery call (you'd better use `this.id`)

Comment: this way i will have to give ids of all the elements present in the div. There can be many elements. For the sake of understanding i was only using 3 elements

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti - Duly noted. Am considering removing the answer completely since the question is a dupe of the asker's other question.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
​$("div").click(function(event) {
   alert(this.id);
   event.stopPropagation();        
});
```

That should alert the id of any `div` you click on but the call to `event.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event bubbling to any parent divs.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/CVLCb/

Comment: but if i click on main div i want to gets its id also which i am not getting

Comment: That's because your inner divs take up all of the space inside `main_div` so when you  click inside it is an inner div that triggers the click event. The `main_div` id is alerted in the fiddle above if you click round the edges of the containing div.

Comment: ok thanks thats very nice of you that you explained me the functionality

Answer (score 0):

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111682/get-the-id-of-the-clicked-upon-div), you can do this:

```
$('div').click(function(evt){
  var currentID = this.id || "No ID!";
  alert(currentID);
})
```

This will show the ID of the div that is clicked.